# Isometries Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra

**In my attempt to prove this result I got up to the point before the part I have highlighted in orange. Is the part highlighted in orange actually necessary?**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, write your question in TeX to make it searchable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is necessary because up until that point in the proof you have only proved that for some $x$, the point $g(x)$ will be itself and for some it could be its reflection. This doesn't make $g$ necessarily either an identity function or a reflection. For example, if
$$
g(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
(x,y)\, & \text{when } x \geq 0 \text{ and } y \geq 0\\
(x,-y)\, & \text{otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$
Then this $g$ acts as identity for some inputs and for others acts as a reflection about the line $y=0$. But it is neither reflection nor identity.